# In a mesh sorting algorithm the row sorting and column sorting steps are interleaved.[Modified Shear Sort]

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, shearsort

We perform one odd-even transposition step along the rows then one along the column(row column sorting steps). The row sorting is done just like that in the case of shear sort. How does it affect the complexity? I have a strong suspicion that it remains the same. Please help me I am stuck.

Comment: Please provide (pseudo) code of the modified algorithm you ask about.

Comment: We first use odd even transposition sorting along the row in a snake like manner i.e. Ascending in odd row and Descending in even. Then we sort a column. Then we sort the next row. Then sort the next column. Repeat until it is sorted.